# React JS Remove cache storage on each version release

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to clear cache storage in my react js project when ever i publish new code to server but i am confuse about how will i do this below mention is the code which i am using to clear cache storage

```
export const clearAppCache = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(`setting/clear-cache`).then(({data}) => {
      if (data.status) {
       caches.keys().then((names) => {
        names.forEach((name) => {
          caches.delete(name);
        })
      })
    }
      } else {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: data.msg});
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
      console.log("Error****:", error.message);
    });
  }
};
```

but at what event I can run this code should I set the old version of the application in the form of a cookie and compare it on each page load or what ??
Thanks.

Comment: What is the condition in which you need to call this "clear-cache" endpoint? If you understand that then you will likely answer your own question.

Comment: condition is when i am publishing new build or new release but i want to know the optimal way to do this i think call server side on each payload to compare app version from browser cookie is not optimal way

Comment: so, at the time of new release i want to clear the cache storage from all users browser

Comment: Ok, can you clarify what that means in the context of this asynchronous action creator that presumably would be dispatched from your UI when it's running?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to "invalidate a cache". We do that with a stored version number, and when that updates we destroy the cache and rerun the store initialization to repopulate the store/state. You can use something similar to know when to clear out any local caches.

Comment: action is using to check the server is released with new version of app or not/api call with check the database value of version and on each release we will update the application version

Comment: so you means that stored version number will be store inside package json or some react config.js file  ??

Comment: Well, in my example its an environment variable injected into builds that we read when instantiating the store, but in your case it sounds like you've an endpoint to check it.

Comment: i think if i store the app_version inside .env file on each build release i can get the new app_version so i can compare it with the cookie and refresh the cache if new version released

Comment: Yes, something like that. I forgot to mention that we store the version number in our redux store, that is persisted to local/persisted storage. Basically when new versions of builds are available and the new version conflicts with what we previously stored, we reset.

Comment: when i am creating new build .env file is not updating until i am not opening application inside incognito mode